# How to edit fxml from code?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml

So I have a `BorderPane` in my FXML, what I want to do is to reload my BorderPane.Center properties so it shows a different pane with different layout,

How can I achieve this? The codes below doesn't work for me.

p.s : sorry for indonesian.

My FXML :

```
<BorderPane fx:id="bPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="fx.HomeMhsController" stylesheets="@css.css">    
<left>
    <VBox spacing="10" fx:id="vbox" id="vbox" prefWidth="100" >
        <Label id="Label" fx:id="biodata" text="Biodata" onMouseClicked="#showIdentity"/>
        <Label id="Label" fx:id="histori" text="Histori Nilai" onMouseClicked="#showHistory" />
        <Label id="Label" fx:id="jadwal" text="Jadwal Kuliah" onMouseClicked="#showSchedule" /> 
        <Label id="Label" fx:id="pilih" text="Pilih Mata Kuliah" onMouseClicked="#chooseSchedule"/>   
    </VBox>
</left>
```

My Controller :

```
public class HomeMhsController{
@FXML private Label biodata2;
@FXML private BorderPane bPane;

@FXML private void showIdentity() throws SQLException{
    init.initializeDB();

    String query="select * from mahasiswa where nama_dpn ='" + MainController.username + "'";
    ResultSet rset = init.stmt.executeQuery(query);

    if(rset.next()){
            String nim = rset.getString(1);
            String nama_dpn = rset.getString(2);
            String nama_blkg = rset.getString(3);
            String tgl_lahir = rset.getString(4);
            String tempat_lahir = rset.getString(5);
            String jns_kelamin = rset.getString(6);
            String agama = rset.getString(7);
            String alamat = rset.getString(8);
            String no_hp = rset.getString(9);
            biodata2.setText(nim + nama_dpn + nama_blkg + tgl_lahir + tempat_lahir + jns_kelamin + agama + alamat + no_hp);
    } 
}
@FXML private void showHistory() throws IOException{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent rootNode = null;
    rootNode = loader.load(getClass().getResource("homeMhs_fxml.fxml"));
    Label dua = new Label("2");
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.getChildren().add(dua);
    ((BorderPane) rootNode).setCenter(pane);
}
@FXML private void showSchedule() throws SQLException, IOException{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent rootNode = null;
    rootNode = loader.load(getClass().getResource("homeMhs_fxml.fxml"));
    Label tiga = new Label("3");
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.getChildren().add(tiga);
    ((BorderPane) rootNode).setCenter(pane);
}
@FXML private void chooseSchedule() throws SQLException{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following code snippet:

```
@FXML private void showHistory() throws IOException{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent rootNode = null;
    rootNode = loader.load(getClass().getResource("homeMhs_fxml.fxml"));
    Label dua = new Label("2");
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.getChildren().add(dua);
    ((BorderPane) rootNode).setCenter(pane);
}
```

you are loading the fxml file again, which is a new instance and different from the one you already have (since this method in its controller class). Moreover you are not doing anything with this newly loaded one (i.e. `rootNode` is not being added to any scene).

Instead just use the existing injected border pane:

```
@FXML private void showHistory() {
    Label dua = new Label("2");
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.getChildren().add(dua);
    bPane.setCenter(pane);
}
```

or more shorter:

```
@FXML private void showHistory() {
    bPane.setCenter(new Pane(new Label("2")));
}
```